# How to add setTimeout to Google Analytics Wordpress

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I have the [Google Analytics for Wordpress plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/google-analytics/) and I want to add a new tracking event:

```
setTimeout("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '15_seconds', 'read'])", 15000);
```

as described [here](http://drawingablank.me/blog/fix-your-bounce-rate.html)

What file should I edit to add a new tracking event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, somewhere in your in footer:

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
(function (tos) {
  window.setInterval(function () {
    tos = (function (t) {
      return t[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(t[1]) + 1) + ':00' : (t[1] || '0') + ':' + (parseInt(t[0]) + 10);
    })(tos.split(':').reverse());
    window.pageTracker ? pageTracker._trackEvent('Time', 'Log', tos) : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Time', 'Log', tos]);
  }, 10000);
})('00');
</script>
```

Hope this helps.